Does Utreexo work with a pruned node?
Does the Utreexo UTXO accumulator work with with a pruned node, or must the entire blockchain be present on my local drive before running Utreexo?

@RedGrittyBrick That's for the prompt to clarify. See my edits. Hopefully they're clearer now.

The docs seem to imply I must have the entire blockchain first:

If you want to run a server you will need the Bitcoin blockchain. Try testnet as it's smaller. (you can get Bitcoin Core from http://github.com/bitcoin/bitcoin or https://bitcoin.org/en/download)

